# I need a simple fifo scheduling in dask-distributed

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I have multiple clients as servers, one scheduler, and one worker with 3 threads.
My clients are async, and when I get a request they use the distributed client.
the call looks like that:

```py
processing_futures = await client.gather(client.compute(response, priority=100, 
                                                        resources={"GPU_RAM": 5}, #the worker has 16 gpu_ram
                                                        fifo_timeout='0ms'))
```

well, the problem is, that when I get a lot of tasks (like more than 1k) the worker actually tries to process all the initial tasks (as described [here](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/scheduling-policies.html#avoid-over-saturating-workers)) first, and this causes the worker to crash, instead the worker could have process by simple fifo, and it would have worked just fine, the problem is that the worker tries to store all the intermediate results in its memory, and it's way too much. It's like embarrassingly-parallel problem, and dask seem to be very challenged by that.

I tried many things, how can I make it process the tasks one by one? or at least like 10 by 10 but not trying to get it all done at the same time..

Is there a chance that it's solvable through the resource system? I thought that if I set the fifo_timeout to 0 then it should make it clear that for each separate request, the queue should not be reordered, please help!

[image: this is a screen shot of the disaster]

Answer (score 1):

Only had to update my dask version on the server, and have this parameter worker-saturation set to 1.1 which is default. that's it it works now thanks!

Took inspiration from [here](https://www.coiled.io/blog/reducing-dask-memory-usage).